# CSS transition top

Tags: css

Estou criando um CSS que simula cartas de um baralho, com cartas e mãos de carta. Quando uma carta de uma mão for selecionada ela é destacada acima das outras.

Isso funciona bem, porém eu gostaria de aplicar um efeito de transição para quando a carta for destacada. Tentei de algumas formas sem sucesso.

Segue o código abaixo:

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <br /><br />
    <div class="hand">
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
.card {
    width: 140px;
    height: 190px;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    border-radius: 7px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    background: white;
}
.hand {
    position: relative;
}
.hand .card {
    position: absolute;
    transition: top .5s;
}
.hand .card:hover, .hand .card.selected {
    top: -2em;
}
.hand .card:nth-child(1)  { left: 1.1em; }
.hand .card:nth-child(2)  { left: 2.2em; }
.hand .card:nth-child(3)  { left: 3.3em; }
.hand .card:nth-child(4)  { left: 4.4em; }
.hand .card:nth-child(5)  { left: 5.5em; }
.hand .card:nth-child(6)  { left: 6.6em; }
.hand .card:nth-child(7)  { left: 7.7em; }
.hand .card:nth-child(8)  { left: 8.8em; }
.hand .card:nth-child(9)  { left: 9.9em; }
```

Link para o sample no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q9DBN/4/)

Esse modelo já estaria OK. O que eu preciso é que o transition funcione com o top, pra que em vez de a carta pular seja exibido um efeito, uma transição, mais suave.

Comment: Que tal dar um flip na carta? [http://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/docs/card-flip.html](http://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/docs/card-flip.html)

Comment: @BrunoRozendo Estaria OK o meu modelo, só o que eu preciso é que o transition funcione com o top, pra que em vez de a carta pular seja exibido um efeito mais suave.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simplesmente defina `top: 0` na mesma regra onde você define a transição. Ambas as "pontas" da transição precisam estar definidas, e você só definiu a final:

```
.hand .card {
    position: absolute;
    transition: top .5s;
    top: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q9DBN/7/

Comment: `+1` - esta é a resposta certa com o detalhe que (me) faltou

Comment: De fato as diversas soluções apontadas me serviriam, mas essa foi a mais didática, pois apontou a falha e a solução...

Answer (score 2):

Acho que isso resolve:

```
.hand .card {
    position: absolute;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transform: translate(0,0em);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0,0em);
    -o-transform: translate(0,0em); 
    -moz-transform: translate(0,0em);
}

.hand .card:hover, .hand .card.selected {
    position: absolute;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transform: translate(0,-2em);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0,-2em);
    -o-transform: translate(0,-2em); 
    -moz-transform: translate(0,-2em);
}
```

Usando `transition-duration` para definir o tempo da transição e `translate(x,y)` para mover a carta.

**[Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/TyBDA/)**

Answer (score 2):

Eu sugiro usar o `margin-top`. Neste caso o CSS podia ser assim:

```
.hand .card {
    position: absolute;
    transition: margin-top 0.3s;
}
.hand .card:hover, .hand .card.selected {
    margin-top: -2em;
}
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/YngDa/)